# Is there any way to restore the deleted contents of a pickle file?

Tags: python, pickle

I wanted to read the contents of my pickle. Accidently while copying and pasting code, I used `'wb'` in place of `'rb'` in order to read the pickle file.

```
with open("abc_contents.pkl", 'wb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```

Due to which my pickle file was overwritten and I lost all the contents. Is there any way by which I can restore the file back to a previous version.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Have you looked into recovery options your OS provides? I'd imagine that's your best bet.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, need to figure out a way to restore the contents. I was hoping for a pythonic way to retrieve the contents though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to restore a pickle file. Just be sure to open the file in append mode `ab`, instead of write mode `wb`, if you do not intend to overwrite the data.

```
with open("abc_contents.pkl", 'ab') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```